# mget to download all files containing ' Q 787 ' in filename

Tags: ftp

I'm trying to download all files from an FTP server that have a specific set of characters in the filename.  The beginning and ending part of the filenames can be different. There is no file extension that I can see.

Sample filenames:

```
001247854 Q 787 SFDFDS
014781259 Q 787 UEIJHF
187852584 S 787 KEINJE
785125873 Q 787 IKUSBD
854792547 S 787 KJDIEP
```

I've been using...

```
mget asterisk dot asterisk
```

...but I only need to get the files containing `' Q 787 '` in the filename.

Mieche

Answer (score 0):

Use mask `"* Q 787 *"` (the quotes are needed because of the spaces):

```
mget "* Q 787 *"
```